# math inside ternary operator JS

Tags: javascript

```js
var h = window.innerHeight;
var mainH = document.querySelector('.mainH');
console.log(h)
h = (mainH === null) ? h : h / 2;
console.log(h);
```

```html
<div class="mainH"></div>
```

I would like to get half of variable `h` using ternary operator:

```
var h = window.innerHeight;
var mainH = document.querySelector('.mainH');
h = (mainH === null) ? h : h/2;
```

This does not work. Someone to help? Thank you

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Did you debug and output the values of these variables?

Comment: if mainH is not null, i. e. `document.querySelector('.mainH')` returns any value, h will be set to h, not h/2. Is that intended?

Comment: Did you mean to do `(mainH !== null)` instead? Other than that it appears to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working fine. There must be some other problem in your code related to the selectors or elements

```js
var h = window.innerHeight;
h = (h === null) ? h : h/2;
console.log(h)
```

Comment: thanks, I had to check variable with console. problem was `h === null` instead of `h !== null`.

Comment: Glad it helped you